# How to Modify Beautiful Soup Output on the Fly?

Tags: python, dictionary, beautifulsoup

I recently started Learning Python and Web scraping using bs4. I queried a website and this is the Output I received in a dictionary:

```
{'title': 'Finance and Automation', 'description': 'Finance and Automation '}
{'title': 'Business and News', 'description': 'Business and News <a href = "cnn.com"'}
{'title': 'Politics and Economy', 'description': 'Politics and Economy <a href = "cnn.com"'}
```

This is basically the code which initializes the dictionary :

```
myList=[]
data = soup.find_all('div', class_='news-description')
for i in data:
    getTitle = title.a.text
    getDesc= desc.a.text
    
    final_data= {
        'title' : getTitle,
        'description' : getDesc
    }
print(final_data)
myList.append(final_data)
```

**And after Printing, I'm getting the Output as shown above**
How can I replace all **cnn.com** which is in 'description' key with something like **google.com** before appending it to the list ?

UPDATE : I ran .replace() , but got this Error :

```
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

I think its **because the First element doesnt have cnn.com**  . How to handle this cases ?

Comment: add the `.replace()` to the text. so: `getDesc= desc.a.text.replace('cnn.com','google.com')`

Comment: will it replace the entire value or just the word cnn.com ?

Comment: it will just replace that string within it. so you should get: `'Finance and Automation <a href = "google.com"'`

Comment: Thanks a Lot. Was struggling . But if cnn.com is not in the value, then programm will crash , right ? How can I handle those ?

Comment: well it won't crash..it just wont replace it. It'll only replace substring `"cnn.com"`. If there's no `"cnn.com"`, it'll just return whatever it orginally is

Comment: It crashes with this Error : TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable  . i think because first element doesnot have cnn.com , that's why ?

Comment: ahh ok. that means your `getDesc= desc.a.text` is returning None. give me sec. I'll put code in as a solution

Comment: Ok, try the code below

Comment: yes , trying,,,,,

Comment: did it work for you?

Answer (score 1):

Give this a try. Let me know if it works:

```
myList=[]
data = soup.find_all('div', class_='news-description')
for i in data:
    getTitle = title.a.text

    if type(desc.a.text) == str:
        getDesc= desc.a.text.replace('cnn.com','google.com')
    else:
        getDesc= desc.a.text
    
    final_data= {
    'title' : getTitle,
    'description' : getDesc
}
print(final_data)
myList.append(final_data)
```

Answer (score 0):

> I think its because the First element doesnt have cnn.com ?

No, it is because `description` is `None` type and not `string`

just check if the description is not `None`

```
for i in data:
    getTitle = title.a.text
    getDesc = '' # initialize empty string
    if desc.a.text:
    # or
    # if desc.a.text is not None:
        getDesc = desc.a.text
```